# Invalid email - How to allow new domains (ie. .club)

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I've got a magento site running on a new .club domain, but the site owner, cannot seem to use their *****@*******.club domain email in the admin panel. 
When you enter a .club in the Store Email Addresses section, you cannot save them as it error's with invalid email address.

What do I need to edit in js/prototype/validation.js
to allow the new 4-6 character domain names, to be acceptable email addresses for the store?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted using this replacement file (from the Magento site) 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/1039603/#t483550

Comment: glad you found an answer to your own question, but please mark it as accepted.

Comment: And please add the information here, not only the link!